# Select drop down gives blank options in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a select element with options inside that will not show when in Firefox.

[image]
This should be showing 3 different options.  In Chrome and Safari it works fine.  I've been looking for a solution and nothing seems to work.  Apparently this is a bug in Firefox.  Here's the html.

```css
.select-field {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #005D5D;
  border-radius: .5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.select-field>select {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0em;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background: url("./menu_arrow.svg") no-repeat 97% 50%;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="games">
  <div className="select-field">
    <select onChange={this.props.gameProp}>
       <option value="streetfighter" label="Street Fighter">Street Fighter 5</option>
       <option value="tekken" label="Tekken">Tekken 7</option>
       <option value="mvci" label="Marvel vs Capcom: Infinite">Marvel vs Capcom: Infinite</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the CSS? can you provide a working snippet with the issue?

Comment: can you upload fiddle or codepen?

Comment: If you dont consider using select due to this bug, then you can simply list the games against radio buttons to be selected, or use datalist html5 feature in which user can type the games name and get suggestion of the available games and with that you can use a similar event in javascript for datalist onselect.

Comment: At first I thought it might not be the CSS because I don't directly change the option tag, but after commenting out all the CSS influencing the select tag it seems to work.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This works totally fine if I run in Firefox, https://jsfiddle.net/prashu421/8b1w8afr/

can you share your CSS as well?

```
<div id="games">
            <div className="select-field">
                <select onChange={this.props.gameProp}>
                    <option value="streetfighter" label="Street Fighter">Street Fighter 5</option>
                    <option value="tekken" label="Tekken">Tekken 7</option>
                    <option value="mvci" label="Marvel vs Capcom: Infinite">Marvel vs Capcom: Infinite</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I updated my post.  It is probably something with my CSS.  Commenting out the CSS fixed it.

Comment: I've updated the snippet with your CSS, https://jsfiddle.net/prashu421/8b1w8afr/3/ I dont see any error, it works fine, clear your firefox cache, and try again

Comment: After slowly commenting out everything I found out that the problem was this part `color:white` in the `.select-field>select` section.  It's strange that it works out in the fiddle, but the fiddle doesn't show the same appearance.

Comment: That's strange, but it's good to know you got it to work now.